# Setting up ssl apache2

Tags: apache-2.2

When in the browser url https doamin.com OK!
When in the browser url https 12.34.567.89 problem with certificate!
How can I view the location of the problem with the certificate error page?
Thank you

setup apache2 
[enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/003hNSDU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because your certificate is registered to a hostname, and when you access the site with your IP, the CN on the cert doesn't match the IP (it matches your hostname) so the browser gives you grief.

Comment: Yes I know, but how to display an error instead of a warning ssl certificate?

Comment: @Charlie You can't. Your website doesn't even get the request, at the point the SSL handshake is made, the browser raises a red flag, and the request is never even sent to the server.